# Why do I get MySQL error: ''questions' WHERE question_number = 1'?

Tags: php, mysql

Why do I get this MySQL error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near questions WHERE question_number = 1' at line 114

My code:

```
<?php include 'db.php' ?>
<?php

//Set question
$number = (int) $_GET['n'];

/*
* Get the Q uestion
*/
$query = "SELECT * FROM questions
WHERE question_number = $number";

//Get result
$result = $mysqli->query($query) or die ($mysqli->error.__LINE__);

$question = $result->fetch_assoc();
?>
```

Comment: Remove quotes from `questions` i.e  `FROM questions` instead of `FROM 'questions'`

Comment: After removing No database selected14

Comment: i also add `questions'

Comment: @TaherKonsowa . . . I removed the single quotes, because those would definitely cause the problem.  Your comment says that they did not.  Please review the question and be sure it is giving the appropriate error.

Comment: Don't use quotes or other stuff around object names, you don't need them. Unless you want problems like you have in this topic.

Comment: You variable `$number` is within a **string**. Do not use it as a string but as a variable instead. `"Select from ... question_number = ". $number;`

Comment: @Tikkes, since the query is inside double quotes `$number` will be evaluated as the actual value and not as a string. No need to concatenate it.